# Matlab - Concatenate integer values with chars in a vector

Tags: arrays, matlab, concatenation

I have a vector with certain numbers as:

```
A=[1 2 3];
```

And I need to get another vector as:

```
B=[G1 G2 G3];
```

Since I cannot mix chars and doubles, I tried to convert the matrix A into a cell array doing:

```
num2cell(num2str(A))
```

And then do:

```
strcat(A, 'G')
```

To obtain the desired result. But doing the num2cell I obtain cell values for thee white spaces (so instead of obteniendo a cell array of 3x1, I obtain Nx1), and then the concatenation with the letter 'G' becomes wrong.

Comment: Your question makes no sense. B as it stands is an array of variables.

Comment: maybe is not clear, but G is a char, and the number is an integer. It is solved below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that `num2cell` makes every single character a separate cell array element by default.

```
num2cell(num2str(A))
%    '1'    ' '    ' '    '2'    ' '    ' '    '3'
```

To simply concatenate `G` to every element, you can just use `numstr` on the column-vector version of `A` which places each string representation of each number in `A` on a new line. `strcat` would then prepend a `'G'` to each line. If you want it as a cell array, we can wrap that in a `cellstr` call to get a cell array.

```
output = cellstr(strcat('G', num2str(A(:))))
```

Alternately, you could just use `sprintf` on each element in `A`

```
output = arrayfun(@(x)sprintf('G%d', x), A, 'UniformOutput', false)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want `B` to be a *single string* with all these values you can simply use `sprintf`. This function accepts vectors as it's second argument so it's very easy to add the same character to every value in `A`.

```
B = sprintf('G%d ', A);
```

Note that this will leave you with a trailing space after your last entry (i.e. `'G1 G2 G3 '`) but this can easily be removed though with:

```
B(end) = [];
```

See the [documentation on sprintf](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sprintf.html) for more examples.